# I accidentally clicked initialize repository in vscode. Now I cannot go back

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code, gitlab

This is how it was

[image]

This is what it is now

[image]

I can't go back. What do I click? What do I do? I closed the Vscode and opened it again, but that also didn't work.

Comment: That's not a problem You initialized `git` on that folder, which means you can now commit and keep track of your file changes. Don't commit changes if you don't want to.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You initialized a [Git](https://git-scm.com/) repository. Git is a version control system. If you do not need Git and want to revert the initialization, you can just remove the folder named `.git` (note that this folder is probably hidden).

Answer (score 2):

You should simply remove the `.git` folder.